# How do i share a second drive using samba on Ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, samba

Im pretty new to linux and am setting up a home server using ubuntu. I set up samba in the terminal using a video guide then realized i had set it up to share the smaller drive ubuntu was on and not the larger drive for storage. I did format the drive so it has a partition. I tried mounting it in the terminal when i set up the samba config to no avail.

Heres what my smb.conf looks like:

```
[c-share]
   comment = C Samba Share
   path = Network files/c-share
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The `path =` needs to be the partition's full path that you see in the terminal, e.g. `/mnt/second-drive` (or a subfolder thereof).

Absolute paths that would start with a drive letter on Windows always start with a `/` on Linux. (Although the file manager might be showing each mounted partition as its own root, like "Network files", that's only for display; in reality everything descends from the single `/` root.)

Ideally, `/etc/fstab` should be configured to mount the partition at some fixed path on startup; you can use "Edit mount options" in GNOME Disks to do that. If it's not mounted on boot, you'll likely need to restart Samba every time you mount the partition for it to recognize that the share is now available.

Comment: i got it working, i made a new dir on that drive and changed the conf to read path = /media/user/drive/c-share